# Image not showing up in designer, Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am new to coding, trying to learn it at school. 
Recently me and my friend has had some problems with getting images to show up in the designer. We are using Blend for VS 2015.

Step by step of what i have done so far:

- Created project
- Created folder Images
- Add existing image
- Set image to Resource in properties
- And then Assets->media->image, and inserted it
- Made sure source path starts with "/"

This is how the designer looks.

[Blend screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzP6p.png)

Its worth mentioning that the image shows up when I run it in the browser.

XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Red">
    <Image x:Name="image" Margin="145,95,155,105" Source="/Images/Vei.jpg" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>

</Grid>
```

My teacher can't help. I hope you can. I really tried reading the old threads but none of it worked.

EDIT:
I have run the VS repair once, and reinstalled twice from different sources (one of them being dreamspark, and the other being the official download page).

I am also running Windows through a virtual machine using Parallells if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your project path for any special characters ? Please see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32372712-b631-4afe-bbb3-2b7b4177742c/cant-see-my-images-in-expression-blend-3-design-view?forum=silverlightbugs

Comment: No special characters.